# Dynamic Entity Framework .ToList() returning error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a Query builder, and I have run into a a bit of a problem. I would like the end user to be able to choose what fields to they would like to be able to select.

my goad is to do something like this

```
public IQueryable Get(Type entityType)
{
    return _dbContext.Set(entityType).AsQueryable();
}
```

However when I try to do something like this `_repository.Get(myType).ToList();`
or really anything i do not compile, and get a message like this.

> IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

can someone please help?

Comment: `ToList()` is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`, not `IQueryable`

Comment: Please read this: http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IQueryable<T>` interface instead of `IQueryable`. `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, and [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`. `IQueryable<T>` has other extension methods like [`ToListAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx) and its overloads.

If you're trying to create a generic repository then define your repository class as generic too. Doing that you could implement `Get` this way:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, 
{
   public IQueryable<T> Get()
   {
      return _dbContext.Set<T>();
   }
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was that I couldn't use`.ToList()` with IQueryable but I could with `IQueryable<T>`. So what I had to do was add an Interface to the entities called `IEntity` and then do `IQueryable<IEntity>().ToList();`